# Using Java-Style Namespace Convention in PHP or is it better to use X?

Tags: php, namespaces, directory-structure

I know that Namespaces in PHP are relatively new and so there are many possibilities to use them. Because it was not usable on the Server i did define my classnames like `folder_folder_classname` if they where in `/folder/folder/classname.php`

Now i want to change that to get better class names. I thought to redesign my class structure to a java based one, like `com\domain\project\folder\folder\class` (e.g. in java: `com.domain.project.folder.folder` package structure) and was thinking that this is a nice solution to avoid any problems with other classes i ever use and don't think about `include()` for my classes any more :)

So now my Questions:

- Is this a good idea or should I use a better system for my php classes?
- Is there a common handling for that in php?
  (I saw that Zend Framework uses e.g. instead of Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract the namespace Zend\Controller\Request with class name RequestAbstract -> no domain and double wording...)

thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely avoid using the domain wording and just prepend the project name itself like Zend does (that way you avoid collision, too). Since you are thinking about restructuring and if you are using PHP > 5.3.0 (which you should) you might also want to consider the [PHP namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

Comment: i want to use PHP Namespaces but im not sure how i should name it in the right way. They always use just pseudo names like my\name and i want to have a link to the folder structure so that i do not need to think about include... so my\Name not in the folder my would be without sens for  me :)

Comment: Your autoloader is responsible for locating classes, so you basically can organize your folders in whatever way you want. But usually things like \Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController reside in a folder structure that makes most sense (namely Zend/Mvc/Controller).

Comment: Okay, thought that there is perhaps more to Check, thanks for your answer

Comment: Might also be worth taking a look at the Symfony 2 framework documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html .  It is a modern frame work that uses name spaces.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for your advice to look into symfony. I was looking for a nice framework and tested ZEND and some others. But i realy enjoin the syntax of Symfony (!)